# Iphone Settings.Bundle -how to update Type field at runtime

Tags: iphone, settings.bundle

Is there a way to update the Type field in a Settings.Bundle file ?

What i need to do is toggle the editing ability of the settings.Bundle file item at runtime.

So, if i had a root.plist item called "name" and its Type is "Title"  after launching the program i'd like to have the ability to change the Type to "Text Field".
What im actually looking for is a way to make the entire Settings uneditable and then editable  again (i'd like to toggle this ability).

If there is a solution at compile time that can be discussed as well.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done. The Settings.bundle can't be modified from the runtime. You'll have to implement a settings screen from within your app.

Comment: i had a feeling, but just wanted to double check.